# 'hl2.exe has stopped working' when I run demos

Tags: garrys-mod

I am trying to record GMod demos, and play back videos of them. But when I try this using in-game tools (by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>, clicking Demos, and press play), all I get is the video playing for 2 seconds, freezing, and the error 'hl2.exe has stopped working'.

Can someone tell me why this happens, and what I need to do to fix it?

Comment: When you say you go to demos and press play, what do you mean? Try playing them through console commands `Playdemo <DemoNameHere>` then use Shift+F2 to see the demo menu.

Comment: @DBS That doesn't work. The game continues to crash.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you recorded them on YOUR system, they should be saved in the Garry's Mod demos directory:

```
C:/programfiles/steam(or valve)/steamapps/<Username>/garrysmod/garrysmod/(demos folder)/(name of the demo)
```

Or on an Apple iMac:

```
~/library/Application Support/Steam/steamapps/common/garrysmod/garrysmod/(demosfolder)/(name of the demo)
```

And for you few on Linux, I am not too familiar, but I imagine it should be about the same as the other two.

In each of those directories, there should be a demos folder named something like `demos` or possibly `recordings` and from those folders, you can find your recorded demos and play them or do whatever.